# Order of definition for function signatures in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion

I have a table of function pointers, and I am trying to determine whether the order of defining the function signatures matters. Looking at my example below, I am wondering why `Method 1` doesn't compile, even though its function pointer type can be determined via decltype. I'd like to know what can be done to make `Method 1` work. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
// Method 1
typedef struct FOO_FUNCS
{
    void( WINAPI * pfnFoo) ();
} FOO_FUNCS;
typedef decltype(&FOO_FUNCS::pfnFoo) PFN_FOO;

// Method 2
typedef void (WINAPI* PFN_BAR)();
typedef struct BAR_FUNCS
{
    PFN_BAR pfnBar;
} BAR_FUNCS;

class FooBarClass
{
public:
    static void WINAPI Foo()
    {
        cout << "Foo" << "\n";
    }
    static void WINAPI Bar()
    {
        cout << "Bar" << "\n";
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    void* pfnFoo = reinterpret_cast<void*>(FooBarClass::Foo);
    reinterpret_cast<PFN_FOO>(pfnFoo) (); <= = this gives me "error C2440 : 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'PFN_FOO'"

    void* pfnBar = reinterpret_cast<void*>(FooBarClass::Bar);
    reinterpret_cast<PFN_BAR>(pfnBar) ();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After expanding typedefs and decltype, `PFN_FOO` is a *pointer to member* of `FOO_FUNCS`, the type of the member being pointer to `void WINAPI ()`. You cannot convert between a pointer to member and a `void*`. That's why you're getting the error.

---

I am not sure, but I believe you may have been looking for one of these:

```
typedef decltype(FOO_FUNCS().pfnFoo) PFN_FOO;

typedef decltype(&FOO_FUNCS().pfnFoo) PFN_FOO;
```

(In the general case, you'd prefer to use `std::declval<FOO_FUNCS>()` instead of just `FOO_FUNCS()` in the above, since that does not require an accessible default constructor).

Or perhaps the simplest (thanks to @Jarod42):

```
typedef decltype(FOO_FUNS::pfnFoo) PFN_FOO;
```

Here is what each of the typedefs does in more detail:

```
decltype(FOO_FUNCS().pfnFoo)
```

The expression is `FOO_FUNCS().pfnFoo`. That is, create a default-constructed `FOO_FUNCS` object and access its data member `pfnFoo`. `decltype()` applied to such an expression yields the type of the data member, which is `void( WINAPI * ) ()`. That's a pointer to a `WINAPI` function taking no parameters and returning `void`.

```
decltype(&FOO_FUNCS().pfnFoo)
```

The expression is `&FOO_FUNCS().pfnFoo`. That is, create a default-constructed `FOO_FUNCS` object, access its data member `pfnFoo` and get its address (in memory). The type of this is "pointer to type of `pfnFoo`;" that means this decltype is equivalent to `decltype(FOO_FUNCS().pfnFoo) *`. So it's `void( WINAPI * * ) ()` - a pointer to a pointer to a `WINAPI` function taking no parameters and returning `void`.

```
decltype(FOO_FUNCS::pfnFoo)
```

The expression is `FOO_FUNCS::pfnFoo`. That is, name the data member `pfnFoo` of class `FOO_FUNCS`. `decltype()` yields the type of this data member, which is again `void( WINAPI * ) ()` - a pointer to a `WINAPI` function taking no parameters and returning `void`.

And your original one:

```
decltype(&FOO_FUNCS::pfnFoo)
```

The expression is `&FOO_FUNCS::pfnFoo`. That is, take the *pointer to member* (sometimes imprecisely called "member pointer") `pfnFoo` of class `FOO_FUNCS`. The type is `void (WINAPI (FOO_FUNCS::*)*) ()` - a pointer to member of class `FOO_FUNCS`, where the member has type pointer to a `WINAPI` function taking no parameters and returning `void`.

The last one is fundamentally different - the other just play around with different ways of accessing the member as a variable (through a temporary, through qualified name), a physical piece of memory if you will. The last one treats it as a "logical" member, as an "offset" within the class. It's the same fundamental difference as between a pointer (`T*`) and a pointer to member of class `X` (`T X::*`).

Comment: `typedef decltype(FOO_FUNCS::pfnFoo) PFN_FOO;` works.

Comment: All three options work...but why? If both decltype(FOO_FUNCS().pfnFoo) and decltype(&FOO_FUNCS().pfnFoo) work, I am surprised that decltype(FOO_FUNCS::pfnFoo) works but not decltype(&FOO_FUNCS::pfnFoo). It would be great if you can elaborate.

Comment: You may prefer to use `std::declval<FOO_FUNCS>()` instead of `FOO_FUNCS()`, default constructor is not necessary accessible

Comment: @Jarod42 True indeed, but given the OP's definitions, both will work. And I found the expressions complex enough as they were. Not to mention the fact that some compilers (VS2010) support `decltype` but not `std::declval`.